# Python: How to efficiently calculate sum with conditions?

Tags: python, performance, loops, iterator

EDIT: I am working on an performance sensitive case, which need to calculate sum or max of data  with user defined checkpoints. Please refer to the demo code:

```
from itertools import izip
timestamp=[1,2,3,4,...]#len(timestamp)=N
checkpoints=[1,3,5,7,..]#user defined
data=([1,1,1,1,...],
      [2,2,2,2,...],
      ...)#len(data)=M,len(data[any])=N
processtype=('sum','max','min','snapshot',...)#len(processtype)=M

def processdata(timestamp, checkpoints, data, processtype):
    checkiter=iter(checkpoints)
    checher=checkiter.next()
    tmp=[0 if t=='sum' else None for t in processtype]
    for x, d in izip(timestamp,izip(*data)):
        tmp =[tmp[i]+d[i] if t=='sum' else
              d[i] if (t=='snapshot'
                   or (tmp[i] is None)
                   or (t=='max' and tmp[i]<d[i])
                   or (t=='min' and tmp[i]>d[i])) else
              tmp[i] for (i,t) in enumerate(processtype)]
        if x>checher:
            yield (checher,tmp)
            checher=checkiter.next()
            tmp=[0 if t=='sum' else None for t in processtype]
```

Original demo for benchmark:

```
def speratedsum(iter, condition):
    tmp=0
    for x in iter:
        if condition(x):
            yield tmp
            tmp=0
        else:
            tmp+=x
```

EDIT: thank to @M4rtini and @Chronial I ran banchmark on the following testing code:

```
from timeit import timeit

it=xrange(100001)
condition=lambda x: x % 100 == 0

def speratedsum(it, condition):
    tmp=0
    for x in it:
        if condition(x):
            yield tmp+x
            tmp=0
        else:
            tmp+=x

def test1():
    return list(speratedsum(it,condition))

def red_func2(acc, x):
    if condition(x):
        acc[0].append(acc[1]+x)
        return (acc[0], 0)
    else:
        return (acc[0], acc[1] + x)

def test2():
    return reduce(red_func2, it,([], 0))[0]

def red_func3(l, x):
    if condition(x):
        l[-1] += x
        l.append(0)
    else:
        l[-1] += x
    return l

def test3():
    return reduce(red_func3, it, [0])[:-1]

import itertools
def test4():
    groups = itertools.groupby(it, lambda x: (x-1) / 100)
    return map(lambda g: sum(g[1]), groups)

import numpy as np
import numba
@numba.jit(numba.int_[:](numba.int_[:],numba.int_[:]),
           locals=dict(si=numba.int_,length=numba.int_))
def jitfun(arr,con):    
    length=arr.shape[0]
    out=np.zeros(con.shape[0],int)
    si=0
    for i in range(length):        
        out[si]+=arr[i]
        if(arr[i]>=con[si]):
            si+=1
    return out

conditionlist=[x for x in it if condition(x)]
a=np.array(it, int)
c=np.array(conditionlist,int)
def test5():
    return list(jitfun(a,c))
test5() #warm up for JIT

time1=timeit(test1,number=100)
time2=timeit(test2,number=100)
time3=timeit(test3,number=100)
time4=timeit(test4,number=100)
time5=timeit(test5,number=100)

print "test1:",test1()==test1(),time1/time1
print "test2:",test1()==test2(),time1/time2
print "test3:",test1()==test3(),time1/time3
print "test4:",test1()==test4(),time1/time4
print "test5:",test1()==test5(),time1/time5
```

output:

```
test1: True 1.0
test2: True 0.369117307201
test3: True 0.496470798051
test4: True 0.833137283359
test5: True 34.1052257366
```

Do you have any suggestion on where I should seek? Thanks!

EDIT: I managed to use the numba solution with callback to replace yield and it is the least effort solution that really works here. So accepted @M4rtini's answer. However be careful with the numba's limitations. With my 2 days try, numba can enhance numpy array index iterations performance but nothing more.

Comment: If you value performance over readability, Python is not the best choice of language.

Comment: whenever x % 100 == 0, you reset the tmp = 0, is that a condition that you are looking for ?

Comment: You need to show more of your code, this part is not where your bottleneck is, if this actually takes .7 seconds to run. This code ran at under 1ms for me.

Comment: sum(range(9901,9999))  your condition is something like this ?

Comment: @BrenBarn It is just for this part, are you suggesting an C module?

Comment: @yopy it is similar condition, but iter is a time series with uncertain iter counts.

Comment: btw map and reduce are two different thing, map will implement your function to each and every element of the xrange and return a list, reduce will apply your function with two argument from your xrange and final result is reduce to only one value.

Comment: Convert to numpy array, do Bolean indexing with your conditional, sum the result.

Comment: @M4rtini I am using [python2.7.6](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.msi) what is your build?

Comment: @KeepThinking Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)

Comment: @M4rtini could it because of lazy iterator?

Comment: So you want to add all elements before the first element that matches your condition?

Comment: Wont that code you're timing simply give the generator object?

Comment: @M4rtini great point ^^

Comment: You should give a better example of a condition. If this is the actual and only condition you are using, you don't even need a loop for this.

Comment: @KeepThinking now your speed test is besides the point of timeit. You need repeated runs to get reliable results. No offense, but your knowledge of python does seem too limited for you to be attempting this kind of optimization. Is your new example now your real condition or once again made up? Because for this problem there is obviously a **way** faster implementation available.

Comment: @Chronial The new example is very close to real, but please wait me to update the problem to complete real one. And the timeit code as well.

Comment: @Chronial Yes I am new to python, I thought it should be as fast as JIT(like dotnet) if I code it right.

Comment: No, python is known for being rather slow at code execution, since it does not have a jit or similar. If you want python with jit, have a look at pypy. Python allows you to write algorithms with great runtime thanks to its readability and clear structure. Its “lines of code executed per second” is rather slow.

Comment: @Chronial Now I understand why this is not a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numba
@numba.autojit
def speratedsum2():
    s = 0
    tmp=0
    for x in xrange(10000):
        if x % 100 == 0:
            s += tmp
            tmp=0
        else:
            tmp+=x
    return s


In [140]: %timeit sum([x for x in speratedsum1()])
1000 loops, best of 3: 625 µs per loop

In [142]: %timeit speratedsum2()
10000 loops, best of 3: 113 µs per loop
```

Comment: I tried numba, it has shown dramatic improvements, should be good choice for research purpose. However considering numba packages dependence and currently not support generator(yield), it is not good choice for my current situation. I was confused by the python performance reputation, and was doubting the slower processing speed compare to C# is because I don't have good understanding of python.

Comment: Based on the updated demo case, could the numpy offer similar performance as numba do?

Answer (score 2):

You seem pretty sure that this is the slow part of your program, but the standard advice is to write for readability, and then modify as needed for performance if necessary - after profiling.

Here's a page I wrote some time ago about making Python faster:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/speeding-python/

If you aren't using any 3rd party C extension modules, Pypy might be a great option for you.  If you are using 3rd party C extension modules, look into numba and/or Cython.

Answer (score 1):

Just to have it done, here is an implementation using reduce (should have horrible performance though) :)

```
res = reduce(lambda acc, x:
            (acc[0] + [acc[1]], 0) if condition(x) else
            (acc[0], acc[1] + x),
            iter,
            ([], 0))[0]
```

This should be a lot faster, but I isn’t as “clean” since it mutates the accumulation list.

```
def red_func(l, x):
    if condition(x):
        l.append(0)
    else:
        l[-1] = l[-1] + x
    return l
res = reduce(red_func, iter, [0])[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Still digesting.

Comment: using l(lower L) as variable is bad habit :D

Comment: run time compare with fair condition:[original: 0.29]
[reduce with tuple(list,int): 0.78]
[reduce with list: 0.67]

Comment: I guess the list operations is the reason why loop in python slower than list comprehension, map and reduce. They are just designed to avoid list append, index.

Comment: In other words, the loop in python is not slow, but the list operation is.

Comment: Try with deque, appending to list i O(n), but appending to deque is o(1).

Comment: @M4rtini: Appending to list is `O(1)`, as you can see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Regarding speed, my tests show that a loop with append is the fastest method. Lists are very fast in python. Function calls however are very slow.

Comment: Maybe this is off the question, but maybe you want to check my updated benchmark result. I got a wrong impression that list comprehension, map things can make big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your original version can be solved with a `groupby`:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(iter, condition):
    if not key:
        yield sum(group)
```

this assumes that condition returns either `True` or `False` or some other set of two possibilities.  If it can return 0, 1, 2, 3, or something similar, you'll want to convert the return to a bool first

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(iter, lambda x: bool(condition(x))):
    #...
```

`groupby` will group items that have the same key in sequence into a single group.  Here, we're grouping together continuous sets of items that are `False` under the condition, then yielding the sum of the group.

This does miss the case where two items in a row are `True` under the condition in which case your original version yields 0.

Comment: good point, but please check my runtime benchmark in updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [itertools.imap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap):

```
iter = xrange(0, 10000)
groups = itertools.groupby(iter, lambda x: x / 100)
sums = itertools.imap(lambda g: sum(list(g[1])[1:]), groups)
```

Note that it produces a slightly different result; there won't be a leading zero in the resulting list and it will produce one extra group since you don't yield the last group.

Comment: Thanks for the groupby method, and sorry for my bad condition example. With my updated condition example, I found it difficult to implement something similar to "lambda x: x / 100".